# Which read-SMS-online services will receive verification codes from Digits?

Tags: ios, twitter, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, twitter-digits

**Background**

I use Twitter's Digits SDK in an app for sign-in, essentially allowing the Users to sign-in quickly use an existing (previously verified by a web app) mobile numbers.  This has worked great during internal testing and everyone likes the feature.

**Digits SDK**

This is part of Twitter's Fabric SDK.  It provides a view controller that appears, allows a User to type in a phone number, verify it with a 6-digit code sent via SMS, and it returns auth tokens, etc.

**Problem**

In order for Apple to review my app, I have to provide a phone number where an Apple employee can receive an SMS [from the Digits verification service] so to be able to authenticate and test my app.

Problem is, I've already tried a number of "Read SMS online" services, but none are receiving the codes from Twitter / Digits.  Without a solution, I'm don't have a way for the Apple review team to get past the first menu of my app.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Hey Dan, We are also facing the same issue currently... Did you get any workaround or any solution for this? If you could help it would be great...

Thanks in advance,
awaiting response.

Comment: Negative, I believe  the Apple tester ended up providing a phone number.